Emulator stuck at starting up in Android Studio after reinstalling and restoring user data
Heading ##Title: Emulator stuck at starting up in Android Studio after reinstalling and restoring user data
Description:
In Android Studio, specifically when using the Pixel 4 emulator on Android 11 (R), I'm encountering an issue where the emulator gets stuck at the starting up stage. Upon inspecting the logs, I discovered that it terminates due to a recurring error. This problem surfaced after I uninstalled Android Studio, reinstalled it, and then restored the user data files to retain my previous settings. I undertook this step because Dart and Flutter were failing to recognize projects that I had been working on for months. Additionally, despite having the Dart plugin installed, it still fails to recognize the projects.
**
**Log Files (repeated error related to emulator startup failure):
2024-05-16 14:12:55,188 [ 109057] INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 30 - [21920:20692:20240516,141255.188:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.13.db\attachments\ea553556-1001-402f-8cad-ae7e9e5a4c11: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-05-16 14:12:55,196 [ 109065] INFO - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 30 - Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
2024-05-16 14:12:55,196 [ 109065] WARN - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 30 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819**

**
I've exhaustively attempted various solutions found online, but none have resolved the issue. If anyone has encountered and resolved a similar problem or has insight into this issue, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you in advance.

Here's one thing that you can try to resolve the issue:
Navigate to Device Manager>[Your Emulators/devices]> Press 3 dots on the right to view options and try Cold Boot Now and try running the emulator again.
Screenshot Attached
If this option Cold Boot Now doesn't work for you, you can try Wipe Data which may remove your emulator specific data including cache, and you can try running the emulator again.

I've already tried wiping data, cold booting, clearing cache, reinstalling Android Studio, and even deleting every file associated with Android before reinstalling Android Studio. Despite these efforts, the same problem persists, and I consistently encounter this specific error, which I am unable to understand.

Android studios latest update came today[21-08-2024] and it fixed the emulator issue.
